# Convert images to compressed video

Tags: video, video-streaming

I have video steam that i convert to images to make some image analyzing.
After my image analyzing - I want to convert the same images ( after i did the image analyze ) compressed video.

Is it possible do to it ( using hardware/software encoder ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish to make a video from images is probably ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i yourimage1 -i yourimage2 -i yourimage3 -vcodec libx264 -an output.mp4
```

Add additional "-i" elements for each image.